# How many wives did king Shaul have?

Tags: history, tanach

I heard that king David had 18 wives.
Approximately how many wives did king Shaul have?

Comment: David has 6 wives; he says he *could have* had 18.

Comment: @DonielF are you sure lihavdil  https://www.gotquestions.org/wives-King-David.html

Comment: See Sanhedrin 21a

Comment: @DonielF thank you, https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.21a.9 but that is only in hevron

Answer (score 8):

The Book of Samuel only tells us of King Shaul having had 1 wife and 1 concubine.

Shaul's wife ([I Samuel 14:50](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.14.50?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> וְשֵׁם֙ אֵ֣שֶׁת שָׁא֔וּל אֲחִינֹ֖עַם בַּת־אֲחִימָ֑עַץ וְשֵׁ֤ם שַׂר־צְבָאוֹ֙ אֲבִינֵ֔ר בֶּן־נֵ֖ר דּ֥וֹד שָׁאֽוּל׃
>
> The name of Saul’s wife was Ahinoam daughter of Ahimaaz; and the name of his army commander was Abiner son of Saul’s uncle Ner.

The woman King Shaul took as a concubine ([II Samuel 3:7](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.3.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> וּלְשָׁא֣וּל פִּלֶ֔גֶשׁ וּשְׁמָ֖הּ רִצְפָּ֣ה בַת־אַיָּ֑ה וַיֹּ֙אמֶר֙ אֶל־אַבְנֵ֔ר מַדּ֥וּעַ בָּ֖אתָה אֶל־פִּילֶ֥גֶשׁ אָבִֽי׃
>
> Now Saul had a concubine named Rizpah, daughter of Aiah; and [Ish-bosheth] said to Abner, “Why have you lain with my father’s concubine?”